# Traefkik Authorization Header

Tags: header, authorization, traefik

I use Traefik as a reverse proxy with an application ([Komga](https://github.com/gotson/komga)) that requires a connection and I would like to know if it is possible with Traefik as on Nginx to define a **proxy_set_header Authorization** so that the proxy automatically connects me to the service.

Exemple for Nginx :

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://6.6.6.6:80;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic a2luZzppc25ha2Vk";
 }
```

Thanks for the help.

[Url Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLAGe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [BasicAuth](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.0/middlewares/basicauth/)

```yaml
# Declaring the user list
#
# Note: all dollar signs in the hash need to be doubled for escaping.
# To create user:password pair, it's possible to use this command:
# echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-auth.basicauth.users=test:$$apr1$$H6uskkkW$$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/,test2:$$apr1$$d9hr9HBB$$4HxwgUir3HP4EsggP/QNo0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and yes I found that, but he doesn't work because the service I use has this url http://komga.domain.com and the url on which to send the Authorization is http://komga.domain.com/api/v1/users/me

Comment: I add in the post the Url Authorization